# How to increase the allocated memory for Ballerina programs?

Tags: out-of-memory, ballerina

I need to run a Ballerina program using the [`bal` command](https://stackoverflow.com) with increased memory.

By default, a maximum of 1024 MB of memory is allocated for a Ballerina program. I am trying to run a quite large application and it needs more memory. How can I increase the allocated memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The executable of a Ballerina program is generated either as an `executable jar` or a `native executable`(2201.7.0 (Swan Lake Update 7) upwards).

Therefore, a Ballerina program can be run using the following methods.

**1. Run using the `bal run` command**

The `bal run` command runs the `executable jar`. Therefore, the ballerina program runs on Java Virtual Machine (JVM). Therefore, we can increase the max memory of the JVM by following the steps below.

1. Find the active Ballerina `version` using `bal --version` command.The output will look like below.

```
 :~$ bal --version
 Ballerina 2201.7.0 (Swan Lake Update 7)
 Language specification 2023R1
 Update Tool 1.3.15
```

Note down your Ballerina version, `ballerina-2201.7.0`

2. Locate  `BALLERINA_HOME`

Linux:

```
:~$ which bal 
/usr/bin/bal
```

Open the `bal`  command file and find `BALLERINA_HOME`

`BALLERINA_HOME = $CURRENT_PATH/../distributions/<$version>`

OS X:

```
:~$ where bal                                                            
/Library/Ballerina/bin/bal
```

Therefore, `BALLERINA_HOME =/Library/Ballerina/`

3. Change the value of  `Xmx` argument

Open the `bin/bal` file in `BALLERINA_HOME`. Locate `CMD_LINE_ARGS` and modify the Xmx argument to increase the memory allocation. For example, to allocate 3GB,

change `Xmx1024m` to `Xmx3g`

[image: command_line_args_jvm]

**2. Run using the `java executable(jar)`**

If you directly run the executable using the `jar` file you can pass the `Xmx` argument as depicted below.

```
java -Xmx3g -jar ./<path_to_jar_file>
```

**3. Run the `native executable`**

If you are running the program using the `native executable` you can pass the `MaxHeapSize` argument as depicted below to run with increased memory.

```
./<path_to_native_executable> -XX:MaxHeapSize=3g
```